# Setting up Smooth scroll with WordPress menu

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am having couple of issues with smooth scroll that I am trying to implement with WordPress menu hyperlink

If I use a simple hyperlink and assign it a class `page-scroll` the smooth scroll works perfectly fine however while generating the wordpress menu I am trying to assign the class `page-scroll`to `<a>` tag but that did not work, so I thought of assigning the `page-scroll` class via JavaScript to the menu as soon as someone `hover` over them.

The hover over does assign the class to the `<a>` inside `#menu-main-menu` but the smooth scroll does not seem to work with it.

here is that JS that i have for smooth scroll

```
$('.menu-item').hover(function(){
        $('#menu-main-menu').children().children('a').addClass('page-scroll');
    });

    $('a.page-scroll').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
          var target = $(this.hash);
          target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
          if (target.length) {
            $('html,body').animate({
              scrollTop: target.offset().top - 40
            }, 900);
            return false;
          }
        }
      });
```

This is the wordpress menu html that gets created

```
    <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<li id="menu-item-23" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-23"><a title="Home" href="http://localhost/wp/">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-25" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-25 active"><a title="About" href="#ct-about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

I will really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Instead of `$()`, try using `jQuery()`

Comment: @ManojKumar, thanks but that did not solve it

Comment: when you alert(target);  after var target = $(this.hash); you get object or undefined? .. try to alert($(this.hash)); and target.length and see what you get

Comment: is there any error in console ?

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef alert($(this.hash)); does not alert anything, but i do see an alert when i am checking with stand alone `<a>`

Comment: @rajatsaurastri no error in console, it just works like an anchor rather than smooth scroll

Comment: can you share the link ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you just bind all your menu items as soon as the page is loaded ? Something like this :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.menu-item > a').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top - 40
        }, 900);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

[edit] By the, I just copied your code in my answer but I feel like there are some errors in it, you might want to check the browser's console when loading your page and make sure all your variables and functions actually exist.

[edit2] If you need to bind all menu items as well as `<a>` tags which have `page-scroll` class, this should work :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.menu-item > a, a.page-scroll').click(function() {
    // your scrolling function
  });
});
```

You could also bind all of your `<a>` tags (I wouldn't recommend that) :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('a').click(function() {
    // your scrolling function
  });
});
```

Comment: very nice, it does seem to work, but is it possible to put a logic that it should work for `.menu-item > a` and `<a>` or I have to have 2 functions for each?

Comment: By the way there are no errors in console at my end

Comment: @Baig ah ok my bad :) I edited my answer with more examples, hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Here You are adding class to your anchor on hover so instead doing this try with adding class to your anchor on load or once your dom is ready for example

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   //add class to your anchor
     $('.menu-item > a').addClass('page-scroll');
});
```

Hope This will solve your issue